# Unexpected varying table row spacing

Tags: tables, spacing, tabularx

When manuelly spacing out the table rows with `\\[10pt]` the actual spacing comes out different. It seems like there is no spacing at all in the second row.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right= 2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}r@{}c@{}lX}
    03/2020 & \ -- \ & heute & \textbf{Company -- Bachelorarbeit} \\
    & & & Test und Evaluierung von Designkriterien für lasergeschmolzene Titanteile im SLM-Prozess unter Verwendung von Heitzelementen\\[10pt]
    08/2018 & -- & 01/2019 & \textbf{Company -- Praktikumssemester} \\ 
    & & & Abteilung Entwicklungs / Standardisierung \\[10pt]
    07/2017 & -- & 08/2017 & \textbf{Company -- Vorpraktikum} \\
    & & & Instandhaltung Mechanik \\[10pt]
    07/2016 & -- & 08/2016 & \textbf{Company -- Vorpraktikum} \\
    & & & Ausbildungszentrum / Montage Antrieb \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would probably be better to set this as a list rather than a table, especially if it gets long enough to need page breaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd usggest using `\addlinespace` from the `booktabs` package. If you want the space to be exactly 10pt large, you can add `\setlength{\defaultaddspace}{10pt}` to the preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right= 2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}r@{}c@{}lX}
    03/2020 & \ -- \ & heute & \textbf{FIT AG -- Bachelorarbeit} \\
    & & & Entwicklung und Beurteilung von Qualitätssicherungskriterien für lasergesinterte Kunststoffteile im SLS-Verfahren unter Berücksichtigung der MDR \\ \addlinespace
    08/2018 & -- & 01/2019 & \textbf{Maschinenbau Silberhorn GmbH -- Praktikumssemester} \\ 
    & & & Abteilung Entwicklungs / Standardisierung \\ \addlinespace
    07/2017 & -- & 08/2017 & \textbf{Maschinenfabrik Reinhausen -- Vorpraktikum} \\
    & & & Instandhaltung Mechanik \\ \addlinespace
    07/2016 & -- & 08/2016 & \textbf{Maschinenfabrik Reinhausen -- Vorpraktikum} \\
    & & & Ausbildungszentrum / Montage Antrieb \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That solves the issue. Is there a reason as to why it comes out inconsistent with \\[10pt]?

Comment: The 10pt are not added below the last line of a table row as you seem to expect, but they are added to the overall height of a table row. For example, compare the row heights (distances between the horizontal lines) in the following example:

Comment: `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}r@{}c@{}lX}
\hline
    03/2020 & \ -- \ & heute & \textbf{FIT AG -- Bachelorarbeit} \\
    & & & Entwicklung und Beurteilung von Qualitätssicherungskriterien für lasergesinterte Kunststoffteile im SLS-Verfahren unter Berücksichtigung der MDR \\[20pt]
    \hline
    08/2018 & -- & 01/2019 & \textbf{Maschinenbau Silberhorn GmbH -- Praktikumssemester} \\ 
    & & & Abteilung Entwicklungs / Standardisierung \\[20pt]
    \hline
\end{tabularx}`